# Are there any academic papers on the merits of imperative over functional programming?

Tags: functional-programming, imperative-languages

There are lots of academic papers on the merits of functional programming floating around. There's also a lot of debate that I see (on the internet) going on about the relative merits of imperative vs. functional programming.

I'm interested to know if that debate extends in academia with actual published papers (the more recent the better I think) discussing the advantages of imperative programming over functional programming.

Comment: Care to link to anywhere you have seen the debate happening?

Comment: Related: [Why Functional Programming](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/51712/why-functional-programming).

Comment: this is the most recent instance that I have come across: http://apocalisp.wordpress.com/2011/05/30/imperative-vs-functional-programming/

Comment: Hmm, well - This is somewhat like asking about the merits of SUVs over gas-sipping hatchbacks. It doesn't kindle the "vive la revolution" spirit IMHO. My 2¢ .

Comment: @greggory.hz: that's not an academic paper, it's some guy's blog. In general, stylistic arguments of "X is better than Y" are useless holy wars. Learn everything you can, discard what doesn't work for you.

Comment: @Steven: there are well-known exceptions. "Terminators versus seperators" for instance. C's `;` rule leads to far less mistakes.

Comment: @MSalters: far less mistakes for whom? citation, please. And is that really on par with entire paradigms?

Comment: @Steven: J. D. Gannon and J. J. Horning, ``Language Design for Programming Reliability,'' IEEE Trans. Software Engineering SE-1(2), pp. 179-191 (June 1975). About 10 times less errors made by programmers, of course. It's a compile-time error so it doesn't lead to runtime bugs affecting users.

Comment: @Steven A. Lowe: I *know* that's not an academic paper. This question is asking for academic papers. I gave that as a response to Oded and in reference to where I said in my question that I see it discussed on the internet, but was wondering if it extended into academia.

Answer (score 3):

Here is one: [Imperative versus functional](http://dl.acm.org.proxy.library.uu.nl/citation.cfm?id=987481.987487&coll=DL&dl=ACM&CFID=40565152&CFTOKEN=42820278)

It is from 1990 however, but by following citations you could find more recent ones.

---

This one only discusses some very basic benchmarking results, and is only cited once, so my previous advice won't get you far. :)

The problem is in order to do a proper comparison you first need to find actual things to compare. Benchmarks of similar applications would seem like a proper comparison, but this only compares languages and not the different paradigms per se. Even if you find a paper which finds a measurable aspect which could indicate that one paradigm trumps the other, this means the paradigm is only more suitable in that specific situation.

That's the same conclusion most people will give you here. One paradigm can be more suitable than the other based on the specific situation.

Comment: .. but it looks crappy and solely discusses benchmarking results. ;p Academic doesn't always mean better. ;p